# Unable to set the list view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This is my xml code. I want to set the listview above the button and below the linear layout names as "titlpricelinearlayout". But I am unable to do this. I am placing above the button but not below that linearlayout. THis is my image which i want like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/body_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="CURRENT ORDER"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/titlpricelinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recipetitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Your recipes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearprice"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="-price"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipeslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonorder"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:text="ORDER"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/tabbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/header" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to use `layout_below=@id/layout2`. it will put `listview` below linearlayout.

Comment: no it shows error if i do like that layout2 is not a sibling...

Comment: It is working for me. change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`in Linearlayout2. it will show you.

Comment: it places now between the layout2 and button button why layout2 tooks more height?

Comment: you have used `android:layout_height="match_parent"` change it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Comment: i changed layout height to wrap content still it  looks like that

Answer (score 1):

Use LinearLayout as parent instead Relativelayout and given weight property to ListView so it will take rest of height on screen :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <include layout="@layout/header" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/body_background"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="CURRENT ORDER"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/titlpricelinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recipetitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Your recipes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearprice"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="-price"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipeslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0d"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/red_button"
        android:text="ORDER"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/tabbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: user wrap content instead

Comment: Okay try to remove background from layout2 and check what happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is this, I changed liner2's height to `wrap_content` and put `android:layout_below="@id/layout2"` in Listview.

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <include layout="@layout/header" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="CURRENT ORDER"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/titlpricelinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/recipetitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Your recipes"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearprice"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="-price"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipeslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonorder"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout2" >
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:text="ORDER"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <include layout="@layout/tabbar" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: ListView]

Comment: @yamuna I have removes background and include Tag and this is how it shows me.

Comment: wait i will give u include and bg

Comment: This is header page link: http://ge.tt/2MeRLF62/v/0?c    this is  footer xml:http://ge.tt/2MeRLF62/v/1?c

Comment: @yamuna Check this out. Put your linearlayout2 below header and then put listview below linearlayout2.

Comment: I am able to see only Item1... which means i am able to see that much of height on;y but below that list view i need to add two text views same as above like price and recipename

Comment: Use scrollView for more space. We have limited space in mobile :P

Comment: Use TAB for footer and actionbar for header. It will save much space for listview.

Comment: But if we use tab bar i cant include that tab bar in sub classes...which means when we are navigating from one class to another we didnt see tab bar at result class

Comment: Join this [Chat Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow).

Comment: I dont hav e20 reputations to talk there...@ Dhaval Gondaliya